# $M \subset E$ of a normed space satisfies this: for a given $x_0 \in E$, every time $f \in E^{*}$ satisfies $f_M = 0$, $f(x_0) = 0$. Prove $x_0 \in M$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I've been trying to do the following exercise:

> Let $M$ be a subset of the normed space $E$. Then for any $x_0 \in E$, $x_0 \in M$ happens if, and only if, $f(x_0) = 0$ for all $f \in E'$ for any $x_0 \in M$.

This is on my weekly exercise list of functional analysis. One direction is pretty trivial. Since we just covered Banach-Steinhaus, Open Mapping Theorem and Hahn-Banach, I've been thinking I'd need to use one of them to prove the other one (on my title). To me Hahn-Banach is apparently the most suitable one, but the thing is, I don't have any hypothesis that $M$ is a subspace or anything, just that it's a subset of $E$. I think I might be working with far too little here for this to be true (because I've been trying to prove it for a long time now to no avail, unfortunately) but I'm not sure. If $M$ was a subspace I think it'd be easier but even then I'm not sure it's even true.

I'd appreciate some help here. Thanks

Comment: First of all, there seems to be a typo, because $x$ is never mentioned except at the end.  In fact the problem as written doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: The statement in the title seems to be something different.  You haven't said what $f_M$ denotes, but if it is meant to be the restriction of $f$ to $M$, then the claim is false in general, but true if $M$ is a closed subspace.

Comment: @NateEldredge It means the restriction indeed. I've managed to do the exercise in the case $M$ is a closed subspace but I'd really like to see some counter examples for the general case.

Comment: I think the statement in the body is still not right.  Do you mean "if, and only if, for every $f \in E'$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in M$, we have $f(x_0)=0$"?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, your statement is equivalent to the one in the body. But I just typed the exercise exactly as my professor put it on the list, so it's not my fault it's poorly written haha...

Comment: Okay, but it's just going to confuse everyone, since it makes no sense.

Comment: In fact, you can show the following: for any $M$ and any $x_0$, the following are equivalent: (1) $x_0$ is in the closed linear span of $M$; (2) for every $f \in E'$ such that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in M$, we have $f(x_0) = 0$.  This implies that the original statement holds if and only if $M$ is a closed linear subspace.  Otherwise, you get a counterexample by considering any $x_0$ which is in the closed linear span of $M$ but not in $M$ itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement in the title is false. If $x_0 \in \overline {M}$ but $x_o \notin M$ then $f|M=0$ implies $f(x_0)=0$ but $x_o \notin M$. I think the crucial assumption that $M$ is closed in $X$ is missing in this statement.